# How to play sound effect forever in cocos2d-x

Tags: audio, cocos2d-x

I am make the android game by using cocos2d-x.
I can't play the sound effect forever. Because it stop after it is played several times.
I think it has limitation as 32 times in SimpleAudioEngine.
Is the way to remove this limitation?
If anyone knows about this, let me know?
Thanks.

Comment: what is the version of your cocos2d-x, and what is your code to play sound effect?

Comment: Thanks for your message. my cocos2d-x version is 2.2.3.
And I am using this code.
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("xxx.wav", false);